# PID tuning in Simulink Matlab , Some explanation in simple terms required

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

What happens behind the scene when the PID block in the Matlab Simulink is tuning and linearising the plant, designing the controller and so on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It linearizes the model around an operating point (either default, or one you specified), and then uses a proprietary algorithm for tuning the PID gains. See http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/slcontrol/ug/introduction-to-automatic-pid-tuning.html for more details.